# transmission-daemon changes config folder on reboot

Tags: bittorrent, cron, ubuntu-16.04, transmission

I am not sure why but transmission seems to be changing my settings on reboot.
The folder where the settings are being held is
/etc/transmission-daemon.

I run the command

```
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
then

sudo transmission-daemon --config-dir /folder/I/want

sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

However on reboot
it switches to the etc folder, and I have to do the commands again.

My solution now
is a bash script that does

```
sudo service transmission-daemon stop

sleep 4s

sudo transmission-daemon --config-dir /root/.config/transmission-daemon
```

with a cron

which works

**However there should be way to get my changes to stick without the bash. When I put in the config command. I am just not sure how**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command

```
sudo transmission-daemon --config-dir /folder/I/want
```

doesn't alter any permanent configuration. It runs `transmission-daemon` and only this instance uses the directory you specified. Note the program places itself in the background, so it seems excessive to run `sudo service transmission-daemon start` just after.

Although [the documentation](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Configuration-Files) says that `$HOME/.config/transmission-daemon` is the default location for daemon settings, it also says:

> Some Linux distributions' start script for `transmission-daemon` use different location.

In Ubuntu `/etc/default/transmission-daemon` is the right place to modify `--config-dir` permanently. Relevant lines tailored to your request are:

```
CONFIG_DIR="/folder/I/want"
OPTIONS="--config-dir $CONFIG_DIR"
```

Note: the syntax is simple and straightforward; I expect it to fail if the path contains spaces. To use any valid path (with spaces etc.) one may fix it somehow (obligatorily with `/etc/init.d/transmission-daemon` or so) but this would be against [the KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). You can simply perform a trick I present down below.

---

An alternative permanent approach is to make your default config path a symlink to the desired real location:

```
sudo mv /etc/transmission-daemon/ /etc/transmission-daemon.old/
sudo ln -s "/folder/I/want" /etc/transmission-daemon
```

I tend to think that modifying config files is *the right approach* in general, *the way it's meant to be*, something *by design*; while a symlink may go as a *cheap trick*. This trick, however, can be very powerful and foolproof. As you can see it can compensate for some limitations of beautifully simple config syntax; or it can save you from learning some awfully complex config syntax, if you ever encounter one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think your first suggestion on how to fix the issue is best. I haven't quite gotten it to work, but will try again. Using Systemd till then.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a changes that you need in **/etc/transmission-daemon** but first **stop** the daemon..

1. sudo systemctl stop transmission-daemon.service
2. Make changes
3. sudo systemctl start transmission-daemon.service

this worked for me .. I was nearly crazy once I notice this .. :D